# Can't create local persistent volume on k8s

Tags: kubernetes

I got `PersistentVolume in version "v1" cannot be handled as a PersistentVolume` error on k8s when I create a local persistent volume.

The output is:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "setLocalPv.yaml": 
PersistentVolume in version "v1" cannot be handled as a PersistentVolume: 
v1.PersistentVolume.Spec: v1.PersistentVolumeSpec.PersistentVolumeSource: 
Local: Capacity: unmarshalerDecoder: quantities must match the regular 
expression '^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$', error found in #10 byte of 
...|ilesystem"},"local":|..., bigger context ...|acity":
{"storage":"10Gi","volumeMode":"Filesystem"},"local":{"path":"/k8sNodeData"},"nodeAffinity":
{|...
```

My yaml files are here.

setStorageClassSSD.yaml:

```yaml
---

apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-ssd-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
```

setLocalPv.yaml:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: dataStorage
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
    volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-ssd-storage
  local:
    path: /k8sNodeData
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: disktype
          operator: In
          values:
          - ssd
---
```

I'd like to know where to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like issue with format. Can you move `volumeMode: Filesystem` to `capacity` level.

```
  spec:
    capacity:
      storage: 10Gi
    volumeMode: Filesystem
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
```